# What about long joins in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It seems very tedious! 
I have a nine table join to join together, where two of the tables is a inner join and the rest 6 is left outer joins.

Is it doable in entity?

Comment: *Long JOINs* !?!? I know of inner, left outer, right outer, cross, full JOINs - but I've never heard of *long JOINs* ....

Comment: 6 left outer joins? Ouch, that's going to be a performance snafu in any situation.

Comment: long joins = many joins I mean! My native language is not english, so forgive my rude handling of the english tongue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly a question but let's say it is. 
Everything is doable using Entity Framework but take a look here first http://www.sqlmag.com/article/entity-framework/microsofts-entity-framework-dbas-141208 for performance suggestions.